# absolute value inequality

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

I would like to know how to solve the inequality $$|x^2-y^2|\leq 2x+2y-4xy.$$
I have tried to solve it by myself and searched in the internet, but didn't come up with an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I forgot to mention that the inequality should be shown for all $x,y\in[0,1]$.

Comment: In addition to the other very helpful comments, see: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5BAbs%5Bx%5E2-y%5E2%5D%20%3C%3D%202%20x%20%2B%202%20y%20-%204%20x%20y%5D&t=crmtb01

Comment: check your question if it is a valid or not before asking.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what "solve" may mean for you. However, did you notice that it is equivalent to
$$
\begin{cases}
x^2-y^2 \leq 2x+2y-4xy \\
-2x-2y+4xy \leq x^2-y^2
\end{cases}
?
$$
Now you have two inequalities without any absolute value, and you can try to "solve" them. Some notion of [conic sections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Cartesian_coordinates) will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Try x=-1 and y=0. Is the inequality satisfied?

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that it should be shown to be true for all x and y between 0 and 1

Answer (score 0):

You've asked *how* to solve: I'd suggest the answer "by checking all possible cases", for some useful choice of cases. For example, you could try

Case 1: $x^2=y^2$.

Case 1a: $x=y$. Then your inequality is equivalent to $0\leq 4x(1-x)$ with solution....(please fill in!).

Case 1b: $x=-y$. Then your inequality is equivalent to $0\leq4x^2$ with solution...

Case 2: $x^2>y^2$. Then your inequality is equivalent to $x^2-y^2\leq2x+2y-4xy$. If we understand 'solve' in the same way as Wolfram Alpha as in @Amzoti's comment, then it makes sense to try to isolate $y$. We can do this by completing the square and rewriting the inequality in the equivalent form
$$(y+1-2x)^2\geq 5x^2-6x+1.\qquad (1)$$

Case 2a: $5x^2-6x+1\leq0$ (corresponding to what restrictions on $x$?). Then (1) gives no further restrictions.

Case 2b: $5x^2-6x+1>0$ (corresponding to what restrictions on $x$?). Then (1) is equivalent to 
$$y+1-2x <-\sqrt{5x^2-6x+1}\quad\hbox{or}\quad y+1-2x>\sqrt{5x^2-6x+1}.$$ To fully solve Case 2b, combine these restrictions with $x^2>y^2$.

Case 3: $x^2<y^2$. etc...

Note: Your additional condition that $x,y\in[0,1]$ should reduce the number of cases and make this run a bit more smoothly.